# React canvas webglcontextlost

Tags: canvas, reactjs, typescript, webgl

How can we define a `webglcontextlost` event handler for React canvas components?

```
class CanvasComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const canvasDOMNode = this.refs.canvas.getDOMNode();
        DrawModule.draw(this.props.drawData, canvasDOMNode);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas id="canvas" ref="canvas" />
        );
    }   
}
```

I tried `<canvas webglcontextlost={ function() { doSomething(); }} />`, also `onWebglcontextlost` and other camelCase combinations, but I get `Unknown prop` error for all of them.

The only way I found working is `canvasDOMNode.addEventListener("webglcontextlost")`, but I'd prefer a React way.

Note: I use TypeScript and also noticed that this property is missing from the React.d.ts on DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically :

> React does not yet recognize the attribute you specified. This will likely be fixed in a future version of React. However, React currently strips all unknown attributes, so specifying them in your React app will not cause them to be rendered.

From : https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html. It is not something that react understand at this point. You are better off adding a manual `addEventListener` as a workaround.